# The bluemix support page has no submit button?

Tags: ibm-cloud

There is no submit button to click after filling up the "ID and Login" page of support https://support.eu-gb.bluemix.net/supportticket/?app=account&index=2 ... Even if I fill all the text boxes I don't a submit button

Comment: How is this a programming-related question? Did you try pressing enter while in any of the text boxes?

Comment: There is a submit button. Can you please switch browsers or start a private session?

Comment: Please direct questions about Bluemix support and your Bluemix account to IBM developerWorks Answers: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html.